# Can I follow users through Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, api

I want to follow users through Facebook Graph API.There is no documentation available.

Comment: That is because it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible via API – most likely because it would just be abused to much, and have app developers subscribing user to follow people without the user being aware of it.

For the web, there is a social plugin available, so that the user can actively trigger a subscription: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button/